# Urgent! Cannot access server in Ubuntu 14.04 from other computer

Tags: 14.04, server, apache2

Today, when I reach the company, the server cant be reach from remote computer. But previous day before I left the company, it still works. No configurations are done between the time I left and enter. Restarted today but still does not work

Comment: And your sure no one fiddled with the system while you were gone?

Comment: Yup. My supervisor also told me that no one touched it. At the starting, ssh connections to it is not possible so no one would be able to ssh inside. SSH is enabled and configured but still cant SSH. I check the apache2 error log and AHD1909: RSA certificate configured for 127.0.0.1:443 does NOT include an ID which matches the server name. What does this means?

Comment: Have you checked network connectivity from local to remote server and vice versa? Checks include network interface, routing and dns. Can you ping server from local to remote servers on the same network?

Comment: Sorry I just reached my company. Just did a check. Internet is currently connected but is unable to surf the net. Ping from remote is not possible. As it is unreachable. How do I solve this?

Comment: What do you mean by internet is connected? Without a general map of your infrastructure it is hard to guess, but as ping from remote is not possible, you either have a misconfigured network adapter on your local server or you have problems in your switch / firewall network. To give an accurate advice I would need to know, how your server is connected to the internet, what infrastructure sits between the server and the internet (switches, hubs, proxys, firewall,...). How are the remote servers from where you try to reach your server is connected to the server in question.